# Moving branch onto rewritten commit

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

My git history looked essentially like this

```
master  | 1 - 2 - 3 - 5 - 6
                  \
feature |           - 4
```

---

Then I made an edit to `3`, by interactively rebasing `2`, and now my history look like this

```
master  | 1 - 2 - 7 - 8 - 9
              \ 
feature |       - 3 - 4
```

Now `7` is `3`, but with the edits, `8` is `5`, and `9` is `6`.

---

Is there a way I can change the `feature` branch so that `3` is dropped, and `4` is branched off of `7`?

```
master  | 1 - 2 - 7 - 8 - 9
                  \
feature |           - 4
```

Comment: Cherrypick it on top of 7.

Answer (score 1):

Simply rebase the feature branch and drop the commit:

```
git rebase -i --onto 7 master feature
# drop the commit 3 and save
# you may have conflicts when applying commit 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, sort of.  You can rebase `4` onto `7` and that's probably what you mean, but `4` won't be `4` anymore, just like `7` thru `9` aren't `3`, `5`, and `6` anymore.

For the provided commit diagram, the simplest way is

```
git rebase --onto 7 feature^ feature
```

replacing `7` with a suitable expression, like commit `7`'s SHA ID, or `master~2` in the given diagram.

If this was just an example, and if there might be an unknown number of commits to keep, then you could do an interactive rebase using `master` as the upstream instead of `feature^`, and then mark commits like `3` to be `drop`ped instead of `pick`ed.